# Does rubber use one or two sulfur atoms to crosslink?

Tags: rubber

Does rubber use one or two sulfur atoms to crosslink?

Comment: It depends and can be more then two. Sulfur's usual form is $\ce{S8}$.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Polymer Database, 
the sulfur bridges formed in the vulcanization process of natural latex are usually comprised of 4-6 sulfur atoms, although this polyssulfide chain can be shorter if the temperature is increased.

> http://polymerdatabase.com/polymer%20chemistry/Vulcanization.html